# Residual finiteness of nilpotent group

Tags: gr.group-theory

It was a theorem of Hirsch that a finitely generated nilpotent
group is residually finite, i.e., the intersection of normal subgroups of finite index is trivial.
My question is: given a finitely generated nilpotent group $G$, is there an explicit construction of a nested sequences of normal subgroups $G_i$ of finite index with
trivial intersection, i.e, $G=G_0 \ge G_1 \ge G_2 \ge...$, and the intersection of $G_i$ is trivial?

Comment: What do you mean by explicit? If $G$ is any finitely generated residually finite group, define $G_n$ as the intersection of all subgroups of index $\le n$. Then $G_n$ is normal (indeed characteristic) of finite index, $G=G_1\ge G_2\ge \dots  $ is a descending sequence with trivial intersection.

Comment: What I mean is that an construction of such nested sequence via its central series of a nilpotent group

Comment: BTW, why do you think that $G_n$ has finite index in your construction? Is  it possible  trivial already?

Comment: Because in every finitely generated group the number of subgroups of given finite index is finite. So $G_n$ has finite index. In particular $G_n$ can be trivial only if $G$ is finite.

Comment: For $G$ torsion-free, I am pretty sure that the lower $p$-central series has that property for any prime $p$, although I can't immediately find a reference. You could define $G_1 = G^k$, where $k$ is the exponent of the torsion subgroup of $G$, and then $G^1$ is torsion-free.

Comment: @DerekHolt that torsion-free fg nilpotent groups are residually-$p$ for every prime $p$ follows from their embedding into the group of upper triangular integral matrices for some size.